# How to find the maximum element value across multiple arrays?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to manually convert a BGR image to HSV. I need to find the maximum pixel value each of 3 image channels (numPy arrays) and create a new array which contains the maximum of the 3 channels.

```
def convertBGRtoHSV(image):

    # normalize image
    scaledImage = image // 256

    # split image into 3 channels
    B, G, R = cv2.split(scaledImage)

    # find the shape of each array
    heightB, widthB = B.shape

    V = []
    for h_i in range(0, height):
        for w_i in range(0, width):
            V[h_i][w_i] = max(B[h_i][w_i], G[h_i][w_i], R[h_i][w_i])
```

I am getting this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

I know this loop is incorrect. I know to access the value of a pixel in an array you must say the location as such as `x[:,:]` but I am not sure how to loop over all the pixels of each image and make a new array with the `max` value of each array element.

If possible I would like to  know how to use a [numPy "Vectorized Operation"](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html) to accomplish this as well as the for loop.

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to the second dimension of a 1-D list in your last line there.

Comment: Hi, can you explain what you mean? I would still like to know how to solve this using the for loop...

Comment: I'll add an answer explaining.

Comment: I think I figured it out... `V`  should be the same shape as `B` which means that `V = np.zeros_like(B)` which would give it the same shape. When you speak of a multidimensional array you are speaking of a list of a list, correct? Eg `V[h_i][w_i]` is accessing a list of a list? But yes, would love to see another answer on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a builtin function for element-wise maximum:

```
V = np.maximum(np.maximum(R, G), B)
```

... and you are done

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(image)

height, width, _ = image.shape

# initialize your output array 'v'
v = np.zeros((height, width))

# loop over each index in ranges dictated by the image shape
for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        # assign the maximum value across the 3rd dimension (color channel)
        # from the original image to your output array 
        v[row, col] = max(image[row, col, :])
```